# main domain .htaccess function seperate to addon domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi guys I believe I have an issue with my .htaccess as my addon domain site is not function properly, due to main domain's .htaccess is taking over the addon domain's .htaccess.

A) is the main domain which which has wordpress installed and its .htaccess is enabled for wordpress functions.

B) is addon domain which has SuiteCRM installed. SuiteCRM is having refreshing problem. I read somewhere else, someone was saying this was due main domain or (A) .htaccess is taking over the (B) .htaccess and restricting addon domain's .htaccess to function.

I was wondering would anyone be able to help me to stop (A) .htaccess from controlling (B) .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have the main domain and add-on domain be in different root folders.
Which you can setup/edit in add-on domains section.

**For example**: public_html/main_domain **AND** public_html/addon_domain

This way the both will work independently.
Hope this helps, and i think this would be an ideal solution instead of creating several rules in .htaccess

If you still want to go down that path i've found a Q/A here that might help !
https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3139428.htm